# Does being vaccinated prevent transmission of disease if you catch it

Tags: vaccination

Each year, many people get the flu vaccine (and I'm sure there are many more other than flu).

Even if you get this vaccine, and from what I've understood, you can still catch the same strain of flu as the one you were vaccinated for! Whilst the vaccine does not make us immune to the flu, we suffer with milder symptoms.

My question seems like common sense, but I find nothing on my searches to back up if a person who is vaccinated can no longer infect others.

So, does this mean during the time where catching the same strain of flu you took the vaccine for you can still be infectious?